# show that event is in progress to all users

Tags: php, node.js, redis, socket.io, laravel-4

I am currently using laravel4 for my web app. I have used [this tutorial](http://www.volkomenjuist.nl/blog/2013/10/20/laravel-4-and-nodejsredis-pubsub-realtime-notifications/) to use the real time notifications. I am running socket.io, nodejs and redis as shown in the tutorial. this is just being used for pubsub as of right now, my main application is a php app using laravel 4.

the problem I am trying to solve is that I want to display a loading gif(you  know the spinning thing) to all users when one user has kicked off an event and continue that until the event has stopped. I know I can accomplish this by firing an event using socket.io to update the page when a certain event is kicked off. this event will likely be  an API call using ajax from the JavaScript side.

The issue is that if the page is refreshed or a new user loads the page they will not be notified that an event is taking place.this is becuase nothing has been published to that channel since the page has been loaded. how do I keep an event open so that as long as this event is going on everyone has a loading gif displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps , if you're using redis , you can put event in other type of data .

Pub/sub is not persistent , so if you're not connected ,you loose information.

You can use a list and put on left (LPUSH) in a channel of user , and deque (RPOP - BRPOP) to give back to users. BRPOP is a good way to do it in nodejs . You make a connection to redis (a connection only use to brpop , because that's can be block on redis ) a send rpop command with callback on a deque.
more information to the [blocking deque list and pattern event notification](http://redis.io/commands/blpop)

If is juste state thats user have to know , you could also use a key (set and del , or with a TTL)